# I want to call a server via post method and it doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, .net, rest, windows-phone-8

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 applicaion. I have to perform a login process and I do that bu sending some data. I used the url of the service via POSTMAN from google chrome. So far so good. I tried with fiddler and although the login credentials were good, I got the answer from the server "invalid request"  because I did not set the Content-type:"application/json". After doing that all worked all. On my C# code I got again a unexpcted answer from the server altough mu credentials are valid. I believe that I did not set the Content-Type properly. Bellow is my code:

```
 public void UserAuthMethod(UserAuthMethod userAuth)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://startaxi.punct.ro/api/init/userAuth");
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Headers[0] = "application/json"; //I tried to add this line but no results
            var postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userAuth);
            var data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(postData);

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            var responseString = request.BeginGetResponse(GetResponseCallback, request);
        }

 void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
            if (request != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
                    var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                    string result2 = reader.ReadToEnd();

                }
                catch (WebException e)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

What's wrong with my code? Any help will be appreciated!
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Adding a header should be like `.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")`. You should just do it using the `.ContentType` like you did before. I guess the issue here is that you are only setting the `.ContentLength` and don't write any real data to the request stream. Thus it has no content data.

Comment: You are only assiging the data length to the request, not the data itself. I haven't had my morning coffee yet thought, so I may have missed something!

Comment: user887675: Headers does not have the Add method

Comment: It's not a direct answer to your question but you could try the WebClient object instead of a HTTPRequest? You can call WebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/json") and then to post your content call webclient.uploadString

Answer (score 1):

Voila the answer:

```
public void UserAuthMethod(UserAuthMethod userAuth)
        {
            WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
            Uri uristring = null;
            uristring = new Uri("http://startaxi.punct.ro/api/init/userAuth",UriKind.Absolute);//Please replace your URL here
            webclient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
            //content
            Dictionary<string, string> toSerialize = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            toSerialize.Add("email", userAuth.Email);
            toSerialize.Add("password", userAuth.Password);
            string JsonStringParams = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toSerialize);

            webclient.UploadStringCompleted += wc_UploadStringCompleted;
            webclient.UploadStringAsync(uristring, "POST", JsonStringParams);
        }

        private void wc_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //try
            {

                if (e.Result != null)
                {
                    string responce = e.Result.ToString();
                    //To Do Your functionality
                }
            }
           // catch
            {
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As two others have mentioned, you are never setting the data on the request! The documentation for HttpWebRequest shows how to do this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx